# Condition for differentiablility

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose I have two functions that are Schwartz class, say $f,g \in S(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose I have another function $\psi(x)$ such that
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \psi(x)f(x)
\end{equation}
I would like to find a way to understand why this means that $\psi$ must be differentiable but I struggle to find a start as I am very new to Schwartz class functions.

I thought maybe smoothness is enough to begin with. In any case, away from points where $f(x) \neq 0$ I have no problems, but somehow I need to find a way to say something about the differentiability fo $\psi$ in general, provided $f,g$ are Schwartz (and not both identically zero).

Any help would be great !

Comment: ψ(x) must not only be differantiable but also mustn't grow faster than polynoms. This question might help you a little. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104565/if-fx-hxgx-is-h-differentiable-if-f-and-g-are

Answer (score 1):

Even if $f$ and $g$ are not identically $0$, $\psi$ doesn't need to be differentiable. Indeed, take $f(x)=g(x)=$ a test function, whose support is contained in $[0,1]$ for example. Theses functions are in the Schwartz class, and the equality $g=\psi f$ is satisfied for each $\psi$ such that $\psi(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$. But of course, out of this interval, $\psi$ is allowed to be anything, in particular not even continuous.

Comment: This is true for finite f and g. But what about other non-finite functions from Schwartz class. ψ has to be differentiable everywhere on R in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by finite $f$ and $g$?

Comment: f and g have compact supports.

Comment: We can take a function $\chi$ which is equal to $0$ on $\mathbb R_-$, $1$ on $[1,+\infty[$ and $0\leq \chi \leq 1$. Then put for example $f(x)=g(x)=e^{-x^2}\chi(x)$. $\psi$ has to  be equal to $1$ on $\mathbb R_+$, but can be anything on $\mathbb R_-$.

Comment: what if f and g aren't equal to 0 anywhere?

Comment: hm, ok that sounds interesting ! have to look into distributions to understand the whole argument but I wanted to do that anyways! So that would mean the proof that I posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104422/help-with-understanding-a-proof-in-fourier-analysis) is not watertight as it relies on $\phi$ being differentiable (last para below the second question) .. is that right ?

Comment: @superM Maybe I misunderstand something but in this case $\psi$ would be the quotient of two smooth non-vanishing functions, so necessary differentiable.